# VBA-Word Extend Revision to the whole word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm analyzing revised documents. They all have change tracking enabled, and contain many revisions.

These documents are required to have revision on the whole word, not part of it. As this revisions are used for QA, I cannot as well flag as revised any words that were not revised.
So I must make words that have revised letters into words fully revised, but cannot touch other words.

I want to automate this. I figured I could do this:

```
dim wrdRange as Range
For Each wrd In ThisDocument.Words
    Set wrdRange = wrd
    If wrdRange.Revisions.Count <> 0 Then
        wrdRange.Text = wrdRange.Text
    End If
Next wrd
```

It's working half way, but every time it encounters a revised word (partially or fully), it will make avery other word revised (there will be a revision count of 1 on them).

So the question is how can I fix this.

Also, I'm not at all sure this is the best way to perform the task. I feel like it isn't. If anyone can offer another direction, I'll gladly follow it (I do not like my approach - specially iterating through every word).

Comment: It seems like this clears the changes from the word. Is there more to the code? You might consider using the Compare Documents feature, which can be set to show changes at the word level rather than the character level.

Comment: No, that is the code. When a word has, lets say, 1 revised letter (one red letter according to display options), I want to make it all revised (red). So here I am replacing the whole word. That does the trick but makes the next word have a revision, even if it had none before. So the sentence gets revised until the end (not my intention).

I'm not sure comparing documents would help.

Comment: Oh, I get it, you're turning on Track Changes first.

Comment: Well, revisor are required to track changes. i'm just working on processing them for QA forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. One word flagged as revision were flagging the next one as revision because they include the trailing whiteaspace. I just shortened the range in this case, and now it works:

```
Dim wrdRange As Range
For Each wrd In ThisDocument.Words
    Set wrdRange = wrd
    If wrdRange.Revisions.Count <> 0 Then
        If Mid(wrdRange.Text, Len(wrdRange.Text)) = " " Then
            wrdRange.End = wrdRange.End - 1
        End If

        wrdRange.Text = wrdRange.Text
    End If
Next wrd
```

I'm not sure yet if this is reliable. I have the feeling that some situations might crash resizing the ranges as I did. I'll know once I run it on production. I will fix/comment here.

Comment: I still think there is a better way to do it. If anyone can provide one, I'll accpept that answer. Include this in such answer if your answer only offers another strategy, as this here will fix the code I provided on the question.